# jQuery hot air balloon - change opacity and position simultaneously in a looped animation

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to create a hot air balloon animation where the balloon periodically rises and falls and when it's rising the #flame div is set to full opacity and when the balloon it falling it is hidden.

The balloon rises and falls fine, but I can't make the flame change opacity in time with it, no matter how I change the timings. I've tried for quite a few different methods, so any input would be very much appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#balloon").everyTime(10, function(){                        
         $("#balloon").animate({top:"100px"}, 1000);
         $("#balloon").animate({top:"0px"}, 1000);

      });


      $("#flame").everyTime(1000, function(){                        
         $("#flame").animate({"opacity": 0, duration: 1000});
         $("#flame").animate({"opacity": 1, duration: 1000});

      });

   });
```

```
<div id="balloon"><div id="flame"></div></div>
```

Comment: Any chance of a (simplified as appropriate) demo at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I trust "everytime" must be some sort of plugin...

```
    $(document).ready(function () {


        var flame = $('#flame');
        var balloon = $('#balloon');

        flame.bind("flameOn", function () {
            // do your baloon animation here
        });

        flame.everyTime(function () {
            var that = $(this);
            that
                .css({ opacity: 0 })
                .animate({ opacity: 1, duration: 1000 }, function () {
                    $(that).trigger("flameOn"); // <-- Triggers AFTER the animation
                });
        }, 4000);
    });
```

The tricky part will be choosing the correct numbers to use for timing...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to replicate a realistic correlation between the flame and rising/falling.  It seems you should have the flame "lead" and provide a completed callback function in the flame animation that would cause the balloon to begin rising.  trying to time both will be unrealistic.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the 'queue' option in animate:
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

if set to false, the animation begin at the same time and not in the order of queue.